# Preventing .NET from checking code signing certificate's revocation status for certain assemblies

Tags: .net, code-access-security, code-signing-certificate, ocsp, certificate-revocation

I'm looking for a way to instruct the .NET runtime, that it shall not check online the revocation status of a code signing certificate with the respective certification authority for certain assemblies. These assemblies run within a SharePoint 2010 web site under IIS in a security-restricted internal network which has no access to the internet and hence cannot query the CA.

We've tried setting a CAS policy to enforce full trust for this code:

```
<CodeGroup
    class="UnionCodeGroup"
    version="1"
    PermissionSetName="FullTrust"
    Name="ShareModel_Strong_Name"
    Description="This code group grants full trust for custom assemblies.">
    <IMembershipCondition
        class="StrongNameMembershipCondition"
        version="1"
        PublicKeyBlob="0024...8cd4"
        />
    </CodeGroup>
```

This setting was deployed as part of a customized `wss_minimaltrust.config` file. However, this has no impact on the mechanism of CRL checking.

Whats the right way to go around this: other / proper .NET configuration, possibly in `machine.config`, some Windows Server 2008 R2 configuration, something else?

Comment: CAS and code signing are two completely different things.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629393.aspx

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, this works. I looked into this setting before, but first the declided it worked in the customer's environment :-D However, I would expect a more granular way to influence the behavior rather than disabling it for the whole machine. Would you post it as an answer?